# How to set a default session value in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, webhooks

I have a Flask app with one function receiving requests. This function can call another task if its not already running in the background. If the task is running in the background then it will call another task. Session seems the way to go to be able to pass data between functions in Flask. However I don't see how I can set a default value with it. What I mean is, when the user sends his first request to the app the function is not running in the background so I should have a variable, eg: running = False, to illustrate this. If running is False : function() running = True. Now the function is running in the background, if the user sends a request while the function is still running then it won't pass the preceeding condition and go to else: function2(). When function is done running it will set running to false again. But so how to have this running variable holding the false value in the 1st place ?

Comment: Use `.get(key, default)` on the session.

Comment: Thank you, works !